# How to build a $K(G,1)$ space for every group $G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the book *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher.

And in page 89 when he explains how to build a $K(G,1)$ space for every group $G$:

He builds a $\Delta$-complex with the $n$-simplices $\left[g_{0},\dots,g_{n}\right]
 $ of elements of $G$, and he attaches to it the $n-1$-simplices with the corresponding vertices (the elements of $G$) and calls it $EG$.
Then, he defines an action of $G$ on $EG$ by: for each $g\in G$ taking the simplex $\left[g_{0},\dots,g_{n}\right] $ linearly onto the simplex $\left[gg_{0},\dots,gg_{n}\right]$. He concludes that this action is covering space action.

**The question**:

I understand that $EG$ is a cover of $EG/G$. Why is the universal cover?

Equivalent question: why is $\pi_{1}\left(EG\right)=\left\{ e\right\} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He argues, beginning on line 6, that $EG$ is contractible (and thus has trivial fundamental group) by a homotopy that slides every point $x \in [g_0,\dots,g_n]$ to $[e]$ along the line in $[e,g_0,\dots,g_n]$.

Edit. Ah, too slow. :)

Comment: yes, but the homotopy $h_{t}$ is not a deformation retract since [e] is not staying in place. Is that still enough?

Comment: @user2359227: But $[e]$ does stay fixed. Besides, a space is contractible if the identity is homotopic to a constant map without conditions on fixed points.

Comment: Observe that for Hatcher a deformation retraction of $X$ onto $A \subset X$ is always rel $A$, but maybe you're thinking of the more common used definition, for which it is indeed a deformation retraction.

Answer (score 2):

Sixth line:" the complex EG is contractible".

Answer (score 1):

This construction ensures that the space $EG$ is contractible and so, in particular, is simply connected and hence a universal cover for $BG=EG/G$.